# Разделить файл на две части

Tags: python

Не особо шарю за Python(вообще не шарю), у меня есть тектовый файл в нем строчки
пример: qwer:qwer1
и мне надо что бы было разделение до точки и после точки, до точки к примеру логин после пароль, как сделать хз(((

Comment: Прочитать файл и потом использовать функцию `split`

Comment: окей я добавил split(":")
Что дальше, в этом и все траблы(

Comment: Надо прочитать файл в переменную, потом к этой переменной применить `split`

Comment: окей вопрос в другом как перевести файл в переменную?) Пиши пожалуйста сразу с примерами, а то я самую малость если такое сделать не могу)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью конструкции `with as` открываем файл `test.txt` в режиме чтения. Метод readlines читает все строки в файле, на выходе получаем список `lines`, к каждому из элементов которого применяем метод `split`.

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        acc, password = x.split(':')[0], x.split(':')[1]
```

Comment: Смотри, я провафлил забыл уточнить, мне надо что бы первая и вторая часть записывалась в переменную

Comment: @weil поправил.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @weil отметь ответ, как правильный, если помогло.

Comment: Я на этом форуме первый раз, так что я хз)

Comment: Если не трудно можешь скинуть ссылки на учебники/ютуб каналы, где объясняют за пайтон.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала прочти файл, но после надо делить не по `":"`, а по переносам строк: `"\n"`. и забери результат сплита в новую переменную `arr`. После идёшь по всем элементам через `for` и собираешь данные

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
text: str = f.read() # твой текст со всеми переносами строк и другим
f.close()
arr: list = text.split("\n") # Твой список строк
d: dict = { # А это просто структура (Прямо как в Си) для того, чтобы представить данные удобно
    "name": "",
    "password": "" 
}
res: arr = [] # Место для результатов перебора
for row in arr: # Пройдёмся по нашему списку строк
    r = d.copy() # Создаём копию структуры
    r["name"], r["password"], *_ = row.split(":") # Первые два значения из словаря забираем в данные о строке, остальное - в никуда.
    res.append(r) # Добавляем в словарь
print(res) # Проверяем содержимое словаря
```